# How to accept traffic from cloudflare only for cloud run via Reverse Proxy

Tags: cloudflare, google-cloud-run

How can we make sure all requests are routed through cloudflare seevers only?

I currently setup dns in cloudflare in proxy mode. I set a custom domain mapping on cloud run and pointed dns records for my custom domain to ghs.googlehost.com.

Wondering how to make sure the traffic is received only from cloudflare to avoid abuses.

**Update**

There is another question about origin pulls but the answer mentions its only possible through OAuth which is not in detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Cloudflare Authenticated Origin Pull with GCP Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746861/use-cloudflare-authenticated-origin-pull-with-gcp-cloud-run)

Comment: Nope. It didnt mention the measures in detail

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve your goal without inserting a proxy that you must build. Google Cloud authorization is OAuth. Cloudflare's servers do not implement OAuth authorization headers.

You should implement OAuth at your clients. However, that will provide for authorization but not selectively from Cloudflare.

Comment: Well, If I have a reverse proxy through cloudflare workers, is it achievable? If so, can you please share how to do that?

Comment: @Ayyappa - A Cloudflare Worker would not solve the problem. To inject a proxy into Cloud Run will require creating a serverless connector and configuring Cloud Run to send all traffic to a VPC. In that VPC you would need another service such as Compute Engine that runs the proxy software validating the Cloudflare TLS certificate. That configuration is complex enough that it defeats the purpose of Cloud Run being a serverless service. Your costs would increase for the connector and VM which would need to run all the time.

Comment: I tried having a NGINX server via GCE but as you mentioned it doesn't make it right as i'm capped by GCE instance and also costs pile up for each environment. Can you suggest how to protect cloud run from spam/abuse in that case and should be scalable like a serverless platform - as ideally this is the reason for all these.

Comment: @Ayyappa You have two choices: configure Cloud Run as public which means anyone can access it or require authorization using Google OAuth. If you require more than that, you must choose a different service and implement your own strategy.

Comment: Anything possible with signed requests so that we can block the invalid requests before even reaching/invoking cloud run instance?

Comment: @Ayyappa - What do you mean by signed requests? The authorization for Cloud Run is managed by IAP (Identity Aware Proxy). That service only supports Google OAuth.